# Number of ways to place 6 people on 6 chairs given that 3 of the people want to be next to each other.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

*What are the number of ways to place 6 people on 6 chairs on a straight line, given that 3 of the people want to be next to each other?* Correct me if I'm wrong but I was thinking like this;

Call the people that want to sit next to eachother: A, B and C

Call the other people: M, Z and F

There are 4 possible combinations of 3 chairs next to each other.
On 3 chairs there are 3! number of ways to place A, B and C on them. So in total there are 4 * 3! number of ways to place A, B and C on the 6 chairs.

Given now that we have placed A, B and C there are 3! ways to place M, Z and F on the remaining 3 chairs.

We now have the final number of ways to place all the people on the chairs as follows:

(4 * 3!) * 3!

Correct or not?

Comment: This looks good.

Comment: your answer seems good as @JohnDouma stated, but i think you must have clarified whether the chairs are arranged in a straight  or circular

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish you are correct. I have updated the question. Thank you